# Код ошибки HTTP 403 в .NET Core HttpClient

Tags: .net-core, http-status-code-403

Пытаюсь отправить http-запрос на мною же только что созданный с помощью ASP .NET Core сервер. Выдаёт либо 403ий код, либо "Система контроля доступа не позволяет выполнить Ваш запрос сейчас, обратитесь к системному администратору...". 
Но главное заключается в том, что точно такой же запрос без проблем проходит из браузера, из скрипта на Python и даже из Power Shell. Проблема только в .NET Core!
Дальше код запроса:

```
using System;

using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Trying_http_request
{
    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await Request();
        }

        public static async Task Request()
        {
            string result = "";
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:56640/api/values");
                result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Response != null)
                {
                    var response = ex.Response;
                    var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    var details = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка:\n" + details);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96208/discussion-on-question-by-v-mor---http-403--net-core-httpclient).

Comment: Частично решил проблему полным отключением прокси. Интернет тоже отключился, но запросы стали проходить. Всё ещё неясно, почему остальными средствами те же запросы идут через прокси без проблем.